# Click fetures in OpenLayers get more information (OpenLayers3 and GeoServer)

Tags: click, openlayers-3, geoserver, feature-selection

I try to bring the information related to a certain polygon that I previously displayed with GeoServer on an OpenLayers3 when I click on that polygon on the map it should show the information and zoom in on the geometry ....

What I have done so far, from what I understood that others have done before me here on the forum:

```
  var tot = new ol.layer.Tile({
              source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
                        url:'http://127.0.0.1:10000/geoserver/ADMINISTRATIE/wms',
                        params: {'LAYERS': 'ADMINISTRATIE:pdf',
                                 'STYLES':'TEREN',
                                  tiled:true,
                                  transparent: true },
                        format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
                        ratio: 1,
                        serverType:'geoserver'
                        
              })
          });   
             
          
          map.addLayer(tot);

map.on("singleclick", function (evt) {
        console.log("test");
          this.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel, function (feature, layer) {
            console.log(feature);
          });
      });
```

Here I try the singleclick event, go to click on the map and display "test" but already feature does not want to display at all :(

```
map.on("singleclick", function (evt) {
        console.log("test");
          this.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel, function (feature, layer) {
            console.log(feature);
          });
      });
```

I am very new to these notions and now I am learning on a small project in which I want to do some basic things, and for that I ask for your help. Thank you!

Comment: For a TileWMS layer you need to use WMS GetFeatureInfo https://openlayers.org/en/v3.20.1/examples/getfeatureinfo-tile.html  As the OpenLayers 3 example is no longer working see the OpenLayers 6 example to see what is should look like https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/getfeatureinfo-tile.html

Answer (score 0):

I tried like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>WMS GetFeatureInfo (Tile Layer)</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://openlayers.org/en/v3.20.1/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
    <!-- The line below is only needed for old environments like Internet Explorer and Android 4.x -->
    <script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js?features=requestAnimationFrame,Element.prototype.classList,URL"></script>
    <script src="https://openlayers.org/en/v3.20.1/build/ol.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map" class="map"></div>
    <div id="info">&nbsp;</div>
    <script>
      var wmsSource = new ol.source.TileWMS({
        url: 'http://localhost:10000/geoserver/ADMINISTRATIE/wms',
        params: {'LAYERS': 'ADMINISTRATIE:pdf',
                             'STYLES':'TEREN',
                              tiled:true,
                              transparent: true },
        serverType: 'geoserver',
        crossOrigin: 'anonymous'
      });

      var wmsLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: wmsSource
      });

      var view = new ol.View({
        center: [0, 0],
        zoom: 1
      });

      var map = new ol.Map({
        layers: [wmsLayer],
        target: 'map',
        view: view
      });

      map.on('singleclick', function(evt) {
        document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = '';
        var viewResolution = /** @type {number} */ (view.getResolution());
        var url = wmsSource.getGetFeatureInfoUrl(
            evt.coordinate, viewResolution, 'EPSG:3857',
            {'INFO_FORMAT': 'text/html'});
        if (url) {
          document.getElementById('info').innerHTML =
              '<iframe seamless src="' + url + '"></iframe>';
        }
      });

      map.on('pointermove', function(evt) {
        if (evt.dragging) {
          return;
        }
        var pixel = map.getEventPixel(evt.originalEvent);
        var hit = map.forEachLayerAtPixel(pixel, function() {
          return true;
        });
        map.getTargetElement().style.cursor = hit ? 'pointer' : '';
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

It does not display the map and gives me this error:

```
Access to image at 'http://localhost:10000/geoserver/ADMINISTRATIE/wms?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&TRANSPARENT=true&LAYERS=ADMINISTRATIE%3Apdf&STYLES=TEREN&tiled=true&transparent=true&WIDTH=256&HEIGHT=256&CRS=EPSG%3A3857&BBOX=-20037508.342789244%2C0%2C0%2C20037508.342789244' from origin 'http://localhost' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
:10000/geoserver/ADMINISTRATIE/wms?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&TRANSPARENT=true&LAYERS=ADMINISTRATIE%3Apdf&STYLES=TEREN&tiled=true&transparent=true&WIDTH=256&HEIGHT=256&CRS=EPSG%3A3857&BBOX=-20037508.342789244%2C0%2C0%2C20037508.342789244:1 GET http://localhost:10000/geoserver/ADMINISTRATIE/wms?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&TRANSPARENT=true&LAYERS=ADMINISTRATIE%3Apdf&STYLES=TEREN&tiled=true&transparent=true&WIDTH=256&HEIGHT=256&CRS=EPSG%3A3857&BBOX=-20037508.342789244%2C0%2C0%2C20037508.342789244 net::ERR_FAILED
Image (async)
nx @ ol.js:719
k.load @ ol.js:646
jg @ ol.js:124
k.fl @ ol.js:387
setTimeout (async)
k.Zo @ ol.js:392
(anonymous) @ ol.js:378
requestAnimationFrame (async)
k.render @ ol.js:389
k.Tk @ ol.js:389
b @ ol.js:15
Na.b @ ol.js:18
Va @ ol.js:20
k.set @ ol.js:20
k.I @ ol.js:21
I @ ol.js:380
(anonymous) @ test.php:33
test.php:1 Access to image at 'http://localhost:10000/geoserver/ADMINISTRATIE/wms?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&TRANSPARENT=true&LAYERS=ADMINISTRATIE%3Apdf&STYLES=TEREN&tiled=true&transparent=true&WIDTH=256&HEIGHT=256&CRS=EPSG%3A3857&BBOX=0%2C0%2C20037508.342789244%2C20037508.342789244' from origin 'http://localhost' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Comment: You need to enable CORS on GeoServer https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/production/container.html#:~:text=Enable%20CORS,web%20browsers%2C%20to%20use%20GeoServer.